# Primefaces Datatable filter values are lost after the datatable is refreshed

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using JSF 2.0 and Primefaces 3.2. I have a main form with a datatable and a button on each row that brings up a dialog with another data table. The dialog has its own form. When the datatable row is selected in the dialog, i process the selection and then refresh the datatable in the main form. After the refresh all my filters on the main datatable are lost. Is there a way to remember the filter values?

**My JSF page**

```
<h:panelGroup id="mainTable">
<h:form id="mainForm" prependId="false">                
<p:dataTable id="cl_grid1" var="item"    widgetVar="mainGrid"
                value="# {controller.items}">


<p:column headerText="Colum1" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{item.myObj.code}" sortBy="#{item.myObj.code}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.myObj.code}" style="float:left" />

                        <p:commandButton id="selectBtn" icon="select"
                            oncomplete="selectDialog.show()" actionListener="#{controller.setMainItem}">
                            <f:param name="selectedMainItem" value="#{item.id}"/>
                        </p:commandButton>



                </p:column>

</p:dataTable
</h:form>
</h:panelGroup>

<p:dialog id="cl_selectDialog" header="Select AAAA" dynamic="true" modal="true" widgetVar="selectDialog" 
    height="500" width="900" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">

        <h:form id="selectForm" prependId="true">

            <p:dataTable id="cl_selectGrid" var="selectorItem"    widgetVar="selectGrid"
                value="# {controller.selectorItems}" selection="#{controller.selectedItem}" 
rowKey="#{selectorItem.id}" selectionMode="single">



            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{controller.processSelection}" value="Ok" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-search" 
                                    oncomplete="selectDialog.hide()" update=":mainTable" process="@form"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Cancel" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-search" onclick="selectDialog.hide()" type="button"/>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

**My Controller**

In my controller all i am doing is hydrating my datatable again.

```
@Component
@Scope("view")
public class Controller extends BaseController implements Serializable {

private List<Item> items;

public Controller() {
    items = new ArrayList<Item>();  
}


@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    loadItems();
}

protected void loadItems() {
    items = //Load items from Database
}


public void processSelection(ActionEvent event) {
    //Add the selected Item and then reload items
    loadItems();
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you refreshing the main table? Do you perform an update to the data that you need to reflect immediately? An update to the table in the DOM pretty much guarantees that you will lose that value. You could try to catch the `filterValue` in a phaseListener and try to repopulate it somehow. According to the javadocs, the table has a [setFilters](http://www.dzeek.net/javadoc/primefacesdocs/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTable.html#setFilters(java.util.Map)) method that might let you reset the filter values. This is untested.

Comment: @Kolossus, Yes i am performing an update to the data so i want the changes to display on the screen. The interesting thing that's happening is if i make the Ajax update from the same <form> as the main table then the filter values are kept, since i have to refresh the main table after an AJAX update from another form, the filter values are lost. I find this a big problem with primefaces, there is mostly not enough documentation or a reason on why things work the way they do.

Comment: @Gowtham: Hi, I'm having a similar problem and I'm wondering if you found a solution to for this problem?

Comment: @Lestard, The only solution is to move my dialog to the same form. The drawback with this approach is you are posting more data than you actually need when you submit the contents of the dialog.

Answer (score 16):

If it is an AJAX Request, you can add on your trigger component a 'oncomplete' method which has :

```
<p: ... update='myDatatableId' oncomplete='myDatatableWidget.filter();' />
```

By this way you will re-triggering current filters on the datatable or you can also clear all filters by using

```
 ... oncomplete='myDatatableWidget.clearFilters();' ...
```

Comment: That's a good solution if you are working on the same page. What about navigating to another section and come back later? How can I solve that situation to clear the filters or restore the last filter values?

Comment: Using `oncomplete` instead of `update` is a good trick to refresh the datatable without losing anything, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We also came up with a slightly more elegant solution than the one posted by kolossus which is as simple as extending the PF Datatable for persistent filter values.

http://www.stickysession.com/?p=258

Comment: Good job, but the PrimeFaces sort hurts even more. To 'restore' it, I need to trigger 1-2 mouse clicks in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Since you must to refresh the table from within its form (so it will preserve the filter state) another solution could be to place a hidden button in the main table form and use it as a 'proxy' by clicking it from your dialog, that way the filter will be preserved, like this

change your button from

```
 <p:commandButton actionListener="#{controller.processSelection}" value="Ok" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-search" 
     oncomplete="selectDialog.hide()" update=":mainTable" process="@form"/>
```

into this (just a simple button that clicks the hidden one)

```
 <p:commandButton onclick="$('#my-proxy-button-id').click(); return false;" value="Ok" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-search"/>
```

and add a new button inside the main table form

```
 <p:commandButton style="display:none;" id="my-proxy-button-id" actionListener="#{controller.processSelection}" 
     oncomplete="selectDialog.hide()" update="mainTable" process=":selectForm"/>
```

using this technique you wont be needed to call for filtering manually and no additional "blinking" will appear on screen